# How can I display all products with a custom link in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to display all the products with pagination on a separate page. This page should have a custom link of "Products" in main menu. I don't want to display the built in menu of opencart. I want my own links like Home, Products, Special Offers, About us. I have been searching around but still no reasonable solution found. I am sort of new to opencart. Thank you

Comment: what you have tried? show us code. we will help you

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. Actually I don't know what should I do. Whether to add a custom page or just playing around with the existing pages.

Comment: I have been googling for last 2 days. Nothing useful found. Just give me a brief of how I can do this.

Comment: Its very disappointing to see people like you who instead of helping out others, try to make their reputation. Don't create bad reputation of such a great network.

Answer (score 7):

File: catalog/controller/product/category.php

1.) Replace

```
if ($category_info) {
```

to

```
if (($category_info) OR ($category_id==0)) {
```

2.) And replace

```
$this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']);
$this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
$this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
$this->data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];
```

to

```
if ($category_id==0) { 
    $this->document->setTitle('all products');
    $this->document->setDescription('all products');
    $this->document->setKeywords('all products');
    $this->data['heading_title'] ='all products';
    $category_info['description']='';
    $category_info['image']='';
} else {
    $this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']);
    $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
    $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
    $this->data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];`
}
```

You can view all products and categoryes by link http://opencart.example.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=0

Comment: excellent solution as it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways to do this, the easiest way is to create a master category 'Products' witch all products belong to. Get the id of "Products" category and use this in your common/header controler to generate link

for example products category id is 100

```
$this->data['all'] = $this->url->link('product/category'.'&category_id=100');
```

Then echo this link in tour header view

Comment: Thanks, I already know this solution but I don't want to use this technique. Because using this technique, all sidebars will show the nested categories in them.  Any better solution ?

Comment: In your model: catalog/category create custom function to getall products from al categories, then create custom controller product/all with will be very similar to pproduct/category controller but will use your custom function from category model to get all products, to save time you can use the same view as product/category.